# Does the female soldier with Kyle Reese in the first Terminator's Future war sequence have a name?

Tags: character-identification, the-terminator, the-terminator-series

Here is the sequence that is being referenced:

She is the soldier with Kyle Reese. She is also not listed on IMDB

Comment: Oh, she died.. :(

Comment: Wow, awesome (and tragic) sequence from the 1st movie. But why didn't Kyle Reese and the other soldier throw their charges under the tank tread when they were mere inches away & then skedaddle, about 20 seconds into the clip? Or run behind it?

Answer (score 10):

Yes and no. In James Cameron's script she's only described: -

> Reese looks over his shoulder at his teammate, a GIRL of about sixteen, gaunt, dirty, heavily armed like himself.

However the novelisation by Randall Frakes & Bill Wisher names her as "Corporal Ferro" (on page 68.) Interestingly while her description is very similar to the script's, for some reason it has her being a year younger: -

> *"He glanced over his shoulder at the surviving member of his twelve-man squad: **Corporal Ferro**, a grim, gaunt, female sapper. Fifteen last Tuesday and armed to the fucking teeth. She was staying close to Reese, anchored to her squad leader like a shadow."*

Comment: In the [earlier (Hutson) novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Hutson_novel)), she's just referred to as "the girl" - *Like some awesome beast of prey, the Hunter-Killer roared through the rubble, coming within feet of Reese and the girl who were sheltering behind the remnants of a stone wall. He watched the H-K as it-clattered on then he turned and scuttled along beside it, keeping out of sight of the gun turret which protruded from its steel hull like a weapon-packed boil on the metal hide.*

Answer (score 7):

[Not everybody in a movie has a name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_%28actor%29).  If [she doesn't have a name in the regular cast](http://www.american-buddha.com/terminator.252.htm) lists, then she just doesn't have a name, and you shouldn't expect anything different.

Comment: I'm baffled how this has six upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

In the book she is Corporal Ferro.  Interestingly, thats the name for the pilot in Aliens.  The actor is not listed.

Answer (score -1):

Stuntwoman Jean Malahni, she did the stunts for Linda hamilton in the movie.

Comment: That may be the actress's name, but not the character's.

Answer (score -1):

Her name is Corporal Ferro. This whole scene is in the Terminator Resistance game. Even the guy in the vehicle is a supporting character in the game, his name is Evans.

Comment: Other answers have mentioned her name, though this answer uniquely ties the name to the Terminator Resistance game. Can you link to a source to verify this? Doing so would improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The Characters name is Charlotte Ferro. Her name can be found in the Terminator: Resistance game. Very recommendable game btw.

The actress is stunt woman Jean Malahni (As Nmartin6 already mentioned)

ps, you are officially my hero Nmartin6, I've been trying to figure out this actress name for a while now!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Both the name and this source have been identified in previous answers.  Please don't post duplicate answers unless you have something substantial to add that isn't already covered.

Comment: This answer is the only one that provides both a first and last name. However, it'd be much better if it included a screenshot of that name as it appears in the game itself.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I've spent a few minutes watching playthroughs and she always seems to be referred to as "Ferro" in the game. I've not found anywhere that she's called "Charlotte", even in her own diary.

Comment: @Valorum That matches my research.  The [Terminator wiki page for Ferro](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Charlotte_Ferro) lists 4 sources, one of which (the Hutson novel) the character doesn't even appear in, and none of the other three give a first name.

Comment: @DavidW - I thought it might be in the production notes somewhere, but I'm struggling to see anything that has a first name

Comment: @DavidW - She appears in the Hutson novelisation (see my [note](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37551/does-the-female-soldier-with-kyle-reese-in-the-first-terminators-future-war-seq/278881?noredirect=1#comment769177_151272) above), but she's considerably younger and referred to as "the girl"

Comment: @DavidW - Since there's no attribution, I've edited the name "Charlotte" out of everything on that Wiki page (and the linked pages). The only thing I can't change is the page title since I'd need to log in

Comment: @Valorum Indeed, nice catch.  I meant to say that she doesn't appear _by name_ but my brain was running too far ahead of my fingers.  (Note that in the very last sentence I just typed I had to go back and insert "ahead," so perhaps my fingers are just way too slow today.)